# Get index of network interface

Tags: c, macos, network-programming

I'm writing simple sniffer for OS X on C
So, I have a problem, I can't get index of network interface.
I use this code:

```
int sockfd=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if(sockfd<0)
  {
    printf("create socket");
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  sprintf( ifreq.ifr_name, "%s", "en0");
  if(ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq)<0) 
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

Problem that identifier 'SIOCGIFINDEX' is undeclared. 
 Index of network interface need for structute sockaddr_ll , if I understand rightly

Comment: Have you included  the `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` in your program?

Comment: Yes, I included this header

Answer (score 1):

You could also try and look at this code.
This will get the interface with the **name** and do something with it. Don't forget to include the header and free the memory when you're done with **ifap**.

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
void do_smth_with_interface(const char *name) 
{

    struct ifaddrs *ifap = NULL;

    if(getifaddrs(&ifap) < 0) {
        printf("Cannot get a list of interfaces\n");
        return;
    }

    for(struct ifaddrs *p = ifap; p!=NULL; p=p->ifa_next) {
        if (strcmp(p->ifa_name, name) == 0)
                // do smth with the interface.
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifap);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding `#include <sys/ioctl.h>` on top of your code would solve your problem!

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write that I included header #include <sys/ioctl.h>
In the file sockio.h identifier 'SIOCGIFINDEX' doesn't exist

Comment: Assuming you wrote the `sockio.h`, check weather you have imported all of these libraries `<sys/socket.h>`, `<netinet/in.h>`, `<sys/types.h>`, `<net/if.h>`, `<netinet/ip.h>`, and `<sys/ioctl.h>`. For me, commenting `<sys/ioctl.h>` reproduces your error. Also, if you want I can put my code in the answer, but it's a little bit different from your implementation.

Comment: I included next headers:
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

Comment: Can I get an index of network interface with help of function if_nametoindex(const char*)"?
For example :unsigned int indexInterface=if_nametoindex("en0");