# What's the equivalent of SIOCGIFINDEX for macOS?

Tags: c, linux, macos, networking, interface

Trying to compile a Linux utility called `mdns-scan` for use on a macOS system.
Here's a side-by-side comparison:

[image]

#### Debian:

Compilation success:

```
root@debian:~# cd /git
root@debian:/git# git clone https://salsa.debian.org/alteholz/mdns-scan.git
Cloning into 'mdns-scan'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 77, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (77/77), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
remote: Total 77 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (77/77), done.
root@debian:/git# cd mdns-scan/
root@debian:/git/mdns-scan# make
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o mdns-scan.o mdns-scan.c
mdns-scan.c: In function ‘main’:
mdns-scan.c:218:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
          ~~~~^~~~
mdns-scan.c:218:25: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
                    ~~~~~^~~~~~
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o dns.o dns.c
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o query.o query.c
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o util.o util.c
cc -o mdns-scan mdns-scan.o dns.o query.o util.o
root@debian:/git/mdns-scan# make install
install mdns-scan /usr/bin/mdns-scan
```

#### macOS:

Compilation failure:

```
user@macos:~$ cd /git
user@macos:git$ sudo git clone https://salsa.debian.org/alteholz/mdns-scan.git
Cloning into 'mdns-scan'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 77, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (77/77), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
remote: Total 77 (delta 22), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (77/77), done.
user@macos:/git$ cd mdns-scan/
user@macos:/git/mdns-scan$ sudo make
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o mdns-scan.o mdns-scan.c
mdns-scan.c:218:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
             ^
mdns-scan.c:218:25: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
                        ^
2 warnings generated.
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o dns.o dns.c
cc -Wall -W -g -O0 -pipe   -c -o query.o query.c
query.c:192:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SIOCGIFINDEX'
        if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq[i]) ipi_ifindex = ifreq[i].ifr_ifindex;
                            ~~~~~~~~ ^
query.c:248:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SOL_IP'
                if (cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_IP && cmsg->cmsg_type == IP_TTL) {
                                        ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [query.o] Error 1
user@macos:/git/mdns-scan$ sudo make install
install mdns-scan /usr/bin/mdns-scan
install: mdns-scan: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

---

#### Code:

Seems this is the code tripping the first error:

```
if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SIOCGIFCONF failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}
```

#### Libraries:

From the GNU standard C library:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
```

#### Detail:

From the `netdevice(7)` `man` page:

```
SIOCGIFINDEX
       Retrieve the interface index of the interface into ifr_ifindex.
```

<sup>***Source:** http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html*</sup>

---

So basically, it provides a way to select a network controller interface from an index. But it's specific to Linux, and not macOS. What can I do? What can I substitute this code with, to port this utility (and maybe others) to macOS; or to add compatibility?

Comment: A quick grep of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/` shows OS X does not use `SIOCGIFINDEX` or `ifr_ifindex`. You should probably show the code around `query.c:190`, where `SIOCGIFINDEX` is used (and not just the `printf`). This may be related: [Get index of network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41529934/608639).

Comment: @jww That's exactly right. It's specific to Linux.

Comment: @jww Sorry I must have pasted the wrong lines. i'll fix it

Comment: It's not letting me edit the question..

Comment: ```if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq[i]) < 0) 
            continue; /* See above why we ignore this error */```

Comment: Full code is here: https://salsa.debian.org/alteholz/mdns-scan specifically: https://salsa.debian.org/alteholz/mdns-scan/blob/master/query.c